# Can PayPal send a payment to other PayPal Accounts?

Tags: angular, paypal, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am using `Ionic2`, and need to integrate `PayPal` into my app.

My app needs to be able to **send and receive** payments to/from **other `PayPal` accounts**.

Is there a way for a Mobile App (`Facilitator`) to allow a `Payer` to make a payment to a `Payee`?

I have looked at the PayPal API's, and I can find how to facilitate a `Payer` to make a payment a `Payee`, if the `Payee` is the `Facilitator`. As then it can register the `Payees` PayPal client Id.  But in my case, the `Payee` does not supply their PayPal client Id (`Facilitator` & `Payee` are separate entities). i.e. The `Payee` is another PayPal Account.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PayPal payout api for transferring PayPal amount from one account to another.
Read the documentation in this link.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch

Comment: Thank you. I will have a read. From the initial glance, that looks like the correct functionality.  Do you know if there's an Ionic/Angular plugin that calls this PaPal functionality?

Comment: This looks like it may be an option that can make payouts and is in nodejs, so will probably plug into an ionic app. I need to investigate a little further. Does anyone have any experience with this api?  https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK